# how to use restored model with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

The model is built as

```py
    class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    
        def __init__(self, num_states, hidden_units, num_actions):
            super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    
            ## btach_size * size_state
            self.input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(num_states,))
            self.hidden_layers = []
            for i in hidden_units:
                self.hidden_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                    i, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='RandomNormal'))
            self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                num_actions, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='RandomNormal')
    
        
        @tf.function
        def call(self, inputs):
            z = self.input_layer(inputs)
            for layer in self.hidden_layers:
                z = layer(z)
            output = self.output_layer(z)
            return output
```

after training, the model was saved as:

```
tf.saved_model.save(self.model, model_path_dir='saved_model/model_checkpoint')
```

Now, I'm trying to restore the model and then do inference as:

```
train_agent = tf.saved_model.load('saved_model/model_checkpoint')

## input_state is an array with shape of (num_states, ) 
action = train_agent(np.atleast_2d(input_state))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable
```

How can I exactly use the restored model?

Answer (score 0):

You correctly decorated the `call` method with `tf.function`, thus, your SavedModel will have the very same method serialized inside.

Thus, you can just call your model by calling the `call` method:

```py
action = train_agent.call(np.atleast_2d(input_state))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got another error:  ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=uint8)
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. The signature saved into the savedmodel is the method definition decorated with tf.function. Thus, since `call` has only 1 parameter, you have to call this method only with a single positional parameter (removing the `False`). I update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figure out how to use the `tf.saved_model.save()` and `tf.saved_model.load()` properly, if anyone could help, it would be great! Current solution is to use `save_weights()` instead. For example:

```
model = Model()
mode.train()
...
model.save_weights(checkpoint_dir)
input_s = np.random.normal(1, 128)
output = model(input_s) ## output a tensor
```

Answer (score 0):

Required code given below

> tf.keras.models.save_model(model_name,path)

```
import tensorflow as tf
#save the model for later use

tf.keras.models.save_model(classifier_model,'F:/Face_Recognition/face_classifier_model.h5')

#Reload the model
classifier_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('F:/Face_Recognition/face_classifier_model.h5')
```